# Multiplying values in array if same

Tags: java

I wanna write a recursive method that follows this logic:

suppose if the array is [3, 3, 3, 3] it will return a value of 30 because the consecutive number for trail[i] are equal to each other. So what happens here is 3 + (3 * 2) + (3 * 3) + (3 * 4) = 30

Another example is [2, 4, 3] it will return a value of 9

I hope this makes sense

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need recursion for this?

Simple loop should do the job:

```
public int sum(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
            p++;
        } else {
            p = 1;
        }
        sum += arr[i] * p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

*update*

Java 8 Stream API may be used to produce the same result:

```
public int sumStream(int[] arr) {
    int[] pp = {0};

    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                    // update the quotient for the i-th element
                    .peek(i -> {
                        pp[0] = i == 0 || arr[i] == arr[i - 1] ? pp[0] + 1 : 1;
                    })
                    .map(i -> pp[0] * arr[i])
                    .sum();
}
```

Comment: yes, of course, that seems the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
  int sum(int pos, int[] trail, int cnt) {
    if (pos >= trail.length) {   // when full array traversed
      return 0;
    }
    if (pos != 0 && trail[pos - 1] == trail[pos]) {         // if previous element is same 
      return (cnt + 1) * trail[pos] + sum(pos + 1, trail, cnt + 1);
    } else {                                                // first element or prev not same
      return trail[pos] + sum(pos + 1, trail, 1);
    }
  }
```

And call this way `sum(0, trail, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned that this could be easily written as an interative function without using recursion but if for some reason you still want a recursive function then it will be something like below:

```
int recursiveHelper(int[] nums, int index, int pow){
if(index >= nums.length) return 0;

if(index == 0)
  return nums[0] + recursiveHelper(nums, index+1,0);
else{
    if(nums[index] == nums[index-1])
       return nums[index] * pow + recursiveHelper(nums, index, pow+1);
    else
       return nums[index] + recursiveHelper(nums, index+1,0);

   }

}
```

Notice how we pass the **pow** variable to track the repetition of integers. If a number is not equal to its previous number, we ignore pow and set it 0. If it is equal to previous number, we increment pow and call the recursive function.

**Note :** I didn't execute this, there may be some typos and errors here but this should give you an idea on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] values = new int[]{3,3,3,3};
        int currentNumber=0,previousNumber=-1,count=1,sum=0;

        for(int i = 0; i<values.length;i++,previousNumber = currentNumber){
            currentNumber = values[i];
            if(currentNumber == previousNumber){
                count++;
            }else{
                count=1;
            }
            sum += currentNumber*count;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum : " + sum);
```